# Setting a breakpoint with gdb when the same source file is used multiple times

Tags: c, macros, gdb

I have a foo.c source file which has the following function implementation:

```
#include "header.h"
void PREFIX(function_name)(){
   ...
}
```

I'll copy this file into two directories (dir1 and dir2). In dir1, I have header.h like this:

```
#define PREFIX(a) prefix1_ ## a
```

and in dir2, I have header.h like:

```
#define PREFIX(a) prefix2_ ## a
```

Therefore, during the linking process, I'll have two different function names.

My problem comes up when I want to use gdb to debug this function and I need to set a breakpoint in a specific line within this function.
If I do:

```
b foo.c:235
```

and 235 is a line inside the function implementation, in which function is gdb going to actually set the breakpoint? prefix1_function_name or prefix2_function_name ?

Is there a way to make gdb set the breakpoint on both ?

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, you should re-think your approach here. Why do you want two different names for the same function? It seems like a way to make the code unnecessarily confusing and hard to maintain. At any rate, I believe it will be in both but I don't know. It seems that you could test it fairly quickly by setting the breakpoint, calling the function both ways, and using backtrace to verify the call path.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just try it out?  When I tried it, it set a break point in *both* files:

```
(gdb) break a.c:5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000e87: file 3/a.c, line 5.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x100000e75: file 2/a.c, line 5.
warning: Multiple breakpoints were set.
Use the "delete" command to delete unwanted breakpoints.
```

If you want to break in only a specific file, just use the full path name to that file to disambiguate.